# How do i insert product name and its information into redirec.phtml in magento?

Tags: magento

The payment gateway gave me this code which is meant to be integrated into to the payment page:

```
Please replace these items with the appropriate data:
• with the ID auto-generated by Gateway for the merchant.
• with the input field of the transaction amount.
• with the input field of the order id.
• with the input field of the product name.
• with the input field of the customer email.
```

with the sample here:

```
<input type="hidden" name="mercId" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="currCode" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="amt" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="orderId" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="prod" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="">
```

Then i try to incorporate it into the redirect.phtml which is working.

```
<?php
// Retrieve order
$_order = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order();
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$_order->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
?>
<form name="mygatewayform" method="post" action="https://sample.com/MerchantServices/MakePayment.aspx">
<input type="hidden" name="orderId" value="<?php echo $orderId; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="amt" value="<?php echo $_order->getBaseGrandTotal(); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="mercId" value="05430">
<input type="hidden" name="prod" value="BLACKBERRY BLACK SKIN WHITE">  
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $_order->getCustomerEmail(); ?>">    
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.mygatewayform.submit();
</script>
```

But each time i try to insert the product name which the customer is buying programmatically `<?php echo $productname = $item->getName(); ?>` is will not redirect me to the payment gateway page it will just stop on the www.domain.com/index.php/mygateway/payment/redirect/. this is what i tried out and it didnt redirect again.

```
<?php
// Retrieve order
$_order = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order();
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$_order->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
?>
<form name="mygatewayform" method="post" action="https://sample.com/MerchantServices/MakePayment.aspx">
    <input type="hidden" name="orderId" value="<?php echo $orderId; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="amt" value="<?php echo $_order->getBaseGrandTotal(); ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="mercId" value="05430">
    <input type="hidden" name="prod" value="<?php echo $productname = $item->getName(); ?>">  
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $_order->getCustomerEmail(); ?>">    
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.mygatewayform.submit();
</script>
```

Please can some tell me what i'm doing wrong pls or rather how to get the product name and information inserted or call it into the redirect.phtml page?

Thanks

Comment: I am definitely sure that `product name` isn't real product name. Gateway providers are does not interest which product you sell. Think simple, if you have more than one product in cart, what will you do?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but each time a customer make an order from our site, there is a need for us to include the product name which will shows up on the final payment gateway page, that is why its necessary to include it. Each time im test running it by inserting a default product name manually it redirect to the payment gate way e.g. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0ffR5TX4SpueUlsWTBMYXZ2MHc/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Are you using google checkout?

Comment: I think you used V-Money, right?

Comment: Abiodun, if you have Gateway provider API documentation just share with me. I should see what they want. Because, you tried to insert product name in the form but you didn't think if they are more than one product in the cart!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this piece of code will fix your issue but If am not mistaken, `getName()` function doesn't work is because of the `$item`.

First, you should load the items that available in the cart.

```
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();

// then loop on items
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item->getName().'<br />';
}
```